# Custom post type getting wrong categories and tags

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, tags

Ok i have a custom post type on my blog called videos, where i only post a video. There's a sceen cap below

[image]

**On the right are the latest post from the custom post type, on the left is the video, and under the video is the date and time, category and tags.
But the problem is that it is getting the wrong, Tags, Categories, and date.
How do i fix this?**

here is the code of that template page below

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Single Videos
*/
?>
<?php get_header() ?>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="container">

<div id="contentfull">



    <?php the_post() ?>

        <div class="entry-wide">
            <center><h2 class="page-title2"><?php the_title() ?></h2>     </center>

            <div class="entry-videoo">
 <?php the_content() ?>



 <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'wpbx' ) . '&after=</div>') ?>


            </div>

 <div id="videosidebar">

 <?php
 $queryObject = new WP_Query( 'post_type=videos&posts_per_page=20&orderby=rand' );
 // The Loop!
 if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
?>

<?php
while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
    $queryObject->the_post();

    ?>

 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

 <tbody>

 <tr>

 <td valign="top" width="1%">
 <div id="videoimg"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf(__( 'Read %s', 'wpbx' ), wp_specialchars(get_the_title(), 1)) ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('video-post'); ?>
                    </a></div>
 </td>

 <td valign="top" width="90%">
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
 </td>

 </tr>


 </table>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 </div>

 <div class="entry-info">

 <div class="entry-meta-top">
                    <span class="entry-date"><font color="#e60288"><b><?php the_time(__('F jS, Y', 'kubrick')) ?></b></font></span>
                    <span class="entry-meta-sep">|</span>
                    <span class="entry-cat">Published in: <?php the_category(', '); ?> </span>


 <div id="sharing">
 <span class='st_facebook_hcount' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' displayText='share'></span><span class='st_twitter_hcount' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' displayText='share'></span><span class='st_plusone_hcount' st_title='<?php the_title(); ?>' st_url='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' displayText='share'></span></div>
            </div>

 <br>
 <?php the_tags( __( '<span class="tag-links"><strong>More On:</strong> ', 'wpbx' ), ", ", "</span>\n" ) ?>


 <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </div>


 </div>

 <div class="entry-commm">

 <?php comments_template(); ?></div>


        </div><!-- entry -->





</div><!-- #contentfull -->
</div><!-- #container -->
</div><!-- #wrapper -->

 <?php get_footer() ?>
```

Comment: Please try to follow the progress of your other questions, before posting new ones. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in how you are displaying the videos on the side. Somewhere you are looping through some posts to produce that list. Notice the last post on that list in the screenshot is an *interview* with once *upon a time* - and thats what the categories and tags are related to.

## Why is this happening?

WordPress stores a global variable `$post` which is suppose to be the post (object) being viewed, and it's this that the WordPress functions use to display stuff like categories and tags etc related to that post.

In this case, the global `$post` has been changed when displaying the sidebar lists. Probably because you've used [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or (worse) `query_posts` ([*see this warning*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Caveats)) or you've used (recommended) [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) but as you've gone through the loop, you've declared the current post to be global (either by declaring `global $post` or using `the_post()` method).

So as you go through the loop, you are over-riding the global `$post` variable, until you get to the last one - and then it stays on that post. This is why you are seeing that post's categories and tags.

## How to fix it...

It depends on how you've made the loop. You can use [`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) if you've used the `WP_Query` object. Or, if you've used the `get_posts`, don't declare the post as global and instead pass its IDs to the functions. Alternatively, you can store the original `global $post` (i.e. the main post) in a temp variable and reset it after the loop. [See an example of that here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Reset_after_Postlists_with_offset).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Stephen thanks for your answer, as you can see i placed my whole php file above, and there you ca see the query and other things, i just don't know which line to change or how :(

Comment: You'll want to use wp_reset_postdata after your `$queryObject` loop.  Just above `<div class="entry-info">` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to steven, i found out the correct place to enter the `wp_reset_postdata`

```
<?php
}
?>
<?php
}
?>
```

and here is where you add the code

```
<?php
}
?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata()
}
?>
```